# Volume Above Half a Circunference and Below a Decentered Cone

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral, cylindrical-coordinates

So I have to compute the following integral:

$$
\iint_D \sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy
$$

where $D=\{(x,y)\enspace :\enspace x^2 +y^2 \le 1; \enspace  y\ge 0 \}$

So, as stated on the title, this is basically the volume of the object above half a circumference with radius $1,$ centered at the origin, but below the cone which is centered at $(1,0)$.

As it is natural, I changed to cylindrical coordinates to solve the problem more easily, only to find I still couldn't calculate the integral. The integral I came across after changing the coordinates was

$$
\int_0^\pi \int_0^1 r\sqrt{r^2 - 2r\cos(\theta)+1} \, dr\,d\theta
$$

I can't seem to progress from there. Is there a substitution I can't see? I would appreciate any help! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If follows your method,
please note the following and  you can get the result(maybe need more calculation):
$$\sqrt{r^2 - 2r\cos(\theta)+1}
=\sqrt{(r-\cos(\theta))^2+\sin^2(\theta)}.$$

$$r\sqrt{r^2 - 2r\cos(\theta)+1}
=(r-\cos(\theta))\sqrt{r^2 - 2r\cos(\theta)+1}\\
+\sqrt{(r-\cos(\theta))^2+\sin^2(\theta)}.$$

But I think the better method is "Coordinate transformation".
Let $$X=x-1,Y=y,$$ then $D$  changes to
$$D:(X+1)^2+Y^2\leq 1,Y\geq0,$$
and also we have $dXdY=dxdy$,
so( also use Polar coordinate transformation):
$$\iint\limits_{x^2 +y^2 \le 1} \sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy
=\iint\limits_{(X+1)^2+Y^2\leq 1}\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}dXdY\\
=\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\cos(\pi-\theta)}r^2drd\theta
=\frac{-8}{3}\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\cos^3(\theta)d\theta=\frac{16}{9}.$$